# Google Maps Stylers

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, styles

For some reason this code breaks when I'm trying to add the stylers to customise the colours of my Google Map, could some one point me in the right direction? What am I doing wrong?

```
function initialize() {

var centerMap = new google.maps.LatLng(52.204872,0.120163);

var myOptions = {
    zoom: 12,
    center: centerMap,
    scrollwheel: false,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    var style= [
      {
        "stylers": [
          { "saturation": 100 },
          { "lightness": 31 },
          { "hue": "#ff6600" },
          { "gamma": 0.9 }
        ]
      },{
      },{
      }
    ]
}

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

setMarkers(map, sites);
infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: "loading..."
    });

var bikeLayer = new google.maps.BicyclingLayer();
bikeLayer.setMap(map);
}

var sites = [
 ['The Frontroom', 52.202977,0.138938, 1, 'The Frontroom.'],
['Fitzwilliam Museum',52.199678,0.119931, 2, 'Fitzwilliam Museum'],
['Wysing Arts centre', 52.182077,-0.06977, 3, 'Wysing Arts Centre'],
['Cambridge School of Art', 52.203825,0.134808, 4, 'Cambridge School of Art'],
['Kettles yard', 52.210851,0.114637, 5, 'Kettles Yard'],
['Changing Spaces',52.199678,0.119931, 6, 'Changing Spaces'],
 ['Aid & Abet', 52.195218,0.136578, 7, 'Aid & Abet'],
['The Junction', 52.190756,0.136522, 8, 'The Junction']
];



function setMarkers(map, markers) {

for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    var sites = markers[i];
    var siteLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(sites[1], sites[2]);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: siteLatLng,
        map: map,
        title: sites[0],
        zIndex: sites[3],
        html: sites[4]
    });

    var contentString = "Some content";

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function () {
        infowindow.setContent(this.html);
        infowindow.open(map, this);
    });
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix my self in the end, my correct code with styles:

```
function initialize() {
var styles =   [
  {
    stylers: [
      { hue: '#F2846A' },
      { saturation: 80 }
    ]
  },{
    featureType: 'road',
    elementType: 'geometry',
    stylers: [
      { lightness: 100 },
      { visibility: 'simplified' }
    ]
  },{
    featureType: 'road',
    elementType: 'labels',
    stylers: [
      { visibility: 'off' }
    ]
  }
];

var mapOptions = {
  zoom: 12,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.204872,0.120163),
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
  styles: styles,
  scrollwheel: false
};

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),mapOptions);

setMarkers(map, sites);
infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: "loading..."
    });

var bikeLayer = new google.maps.BicyclingLayer();
bikeLayer.setMap(map);

}

var sites = [
['The Frontroom', 52.202977,0.138938, 1, 'The Frontroom.'],
];



function setMarkers(map, markers) {

for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    var sites = markers[i];
    var siteLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(sites[1], sites[2]);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: siteLatLng,
        map: map,
        title: sites[0],
        zIndex: sites[3],
        html: sites[4]
    });

    var contentString = "Some content";

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function () {
        infowindow.setContent(this.html);
        infowindow.open(map, this);
    });
}
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your myOptions should be formatted as below (see the section after the original word "style":

```
var myOptions = {
    zoom: 12,
    center: centerMap,
    scrollwheel: false,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    styles: [
      {
        "stylers": [
          { "saturation": 100 },
          { "lightness": 31 },
          { "hue": "#ff6600" },
          { "gamma": 0.9 }
        ]
      },{
      },{
      }
    ]
}
```

I moved a couple of things around as well.  Here's a working JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VX8TJ/

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem in the myOptions array (the `var` before style), here is what you need:

```
var myOptions = {
    zoom: 12,
    center: centerMap,
    scrollwheel: false,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    [
      {
        "stylers": [
          { "saturation": 100 },
          { "lightness": 31 },
          { "hue": "#ff6600" },
          { "gamma": 0.9 }
        ]
      },{
      },{
      }
    ]
};
```